Designing CaA-able Character Aspects
An interesting detail about Create an Advantage actions is that they can be used to target an existing Aspect to add (more) Free Invocations to it, so long as it gets past the bogus rule, of course. That means that so long as the Character Aspects (such as the High Concept, Trouble &c.) are suitable, one can target them too. Of course, for many concepts, it will not make sense (e.g. there's probably nothing Tyler can do to leverage his Irresponsible But Ridiculously Lucky Starship Captain Aspect).
But suppose you're picking Aspects deliberately to be compatible with CaAing. What are the best practices for achieving such compatibility? So far I found Tianxia's Form Aspects as the main 'canonical' example of what an Free Invocation-stacking Character Aspect looks like; are there other examples of Aspect types that are a natural fit for it?

Creating an advantage on a character identity aspect is a weird enough operation that you shouldn't just be gating it behind how the aspect is worded.
Every roll in Fate is both a simple mechanical operation and indicative of some element of the story, and it's the overall story setup that makes creating an advantage specifically on a character identity aspect so tricky. Rather than individual players taking steps to make their identity aspects work better, it's more a matter of the GM structuring the story such that the action makes sense.
Mechanical Distinction
From a mechanical perspective there's only a small distinction between using Create an Advantage to put free invokes on an existing Aspect versus using Create an Advantage to create a novel, non-conflicting Aspect with some free invokes.
The overall results are about the same in practice, since the boost you get on a tie for a novel aspect is pretty much the same as the free invoke you put on an existing aspect on a tie. You don't create the novel aspect, but since you weren't trying to create it to conflict with some other aspect in the scene, that doesn't particularly matter.
The one distinction is that free invokes last for as long as the Aspect does. For one created in the scene it's probably going to fall off at the end, unless the new scene shares some relevant common elements. On your character? Well, that one lasts until you change it out yourself. And that's the part that makes finding the story to go along with it so tricky.
Narrative Distinction
An Aspect is not a complete description of all the things it could possibly refer to; at best, it's a pithy summary. This is especially true of character aspects, which are a high concept, a trouble, and three more aspects to summarize a backstory. So when you're creating an advantage on a character aspect, the following things must be true:

the actions you're taking can't be interpreted to boost anything more narrowly scoped than an important third of your backstory
or, heck it, your whole entire self
further, their benefits have an indefinite duration and can apply to any future action where that important third of your backstory (or, heck it, your whole entire self) matters

Even though you can Create an Advantage at any old time (except when you're involved in a structured play element like a Challenge when that's not an option) that set of conditions doesn't exactly seem like it's going to be true any old time, does it?
That's the real difficulty with creating an advantage on a character identity aspect. It needs to be set up properly in the story, and certainly while changing the wording of a particular character identity aspect might help, it's always going to be hard.
How You Might Do It
Here are some ideas for how to set up your game's story such that it makes sense for your players to create an advantage on an identity aspect.
A Sensibly Narrower Identity. If your game is structured such that it makes sense that every character is going to have their own take on a thing that everybody shares in common, that thing is probably going to be a character aspect. It could be an order of knights where everybody wields a dramatically different weapon or source of power, or an adventure family where everybody has a different role in the family, or a romantic fantasy where everybody champions a different heroic virtue. As a narrower aspect, it makes a little more sense to get built up even in a casual scene.
A Sensibly Narrow Identity (+1). "But wait", you say, "if all my players give up one aspect to be about this narrow thing because of the game setting, now they only have two aspects to do their entire backstory." Nobody's stopping you from just giving people as many extra starting aspects as they need to have, and a common feature of the setting that everyone's expected to share is a great excuse to have another aspect slot. This is effectively what Tianxia does - as you can see on the sample characters, everybody still has their standard five character aspects, and investing some of their starting resources into unlocking a kung fu style has additionally given them that style's Form aspect.
Specially-Framed Scenes. While it can be narratively difficult to justify creating an advantage on a character identity aspect at any old time, you can frame a stretch of scenes to make it clear that they're not just any old time. The ever-popular preparation montage is one of those! Even the things that are shown on-screen are just assumed to hint at a bunch of similar stuff that won't be filmed for brevity's sake, and in that kind of environment, stacking invokes on a whole slice of/entire character makes a lot more sense. Show Irresponsible Captain Tylor just chatting it up and/or partying down with the crew, as appropriate, and there's your justification to use Rapport to put a couple free invokes on his topline aspect.
Difficulty and Pressure. Wrath of the Autarch integrates universally-applicable aspects in the form of stronghold aspects. All of its play elements are highly structured, and trying to reinforce a stronghold aspect is not only harder than most other actions you can take, you do it as an alternative to trying to progress in the structured play element. The added cost and difficulty actually help get over the narrative bumps a little, in that what you're doing is framed as more difficult than other sorts of creating an advantage, but you also need to structure your game such that when the players have the option of reinforcing their character aspects they're also explicitly on a clock.
